# How to create String ObjectId with Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Without dealing with storing a GAE Entity with `Long` id and converting value of the associated `Key` to String, what is the way to generate MongoDB-like `ObjectId` within the GAE environment.

Plainly using the `ObjectId.java` from MongoDB does not work due to its access to GAE restricted classes.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but you should be able to create a Mongo ObjectId from a UUID.  On GAE try, ObjectId id = new ObjectId(UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(1,24));

Comment: Yes I did, and actually it worked for me, I just need to trim off the dashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a Mongo ObjectId from a UUID.

On GAE:

```
ObjectId id = new ObjectId(UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "").substring(1,24));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "name" to create ID, GAE keys can be created from a custom string which is your ObjectId and when you are trying to a get by ID, use that string to quickly create a key this way you do not need to use Long Id's at all.